# Using sed to find and delete across multiple files recursively

Tags: sed

How can I do a string match against, for example:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="
```

Then delete that whole line every time a match is found?

I'm looking to do this for all files in the current directory and below.

I'm also new to sed.

Comment: You are not using `sed` to parse HTML, are you?

Comment: I'm using it to find that line across HTML files and remove it, so I guess yes. Is that bad?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1030675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to the question: "How do I do x to all files recursively?", the answer is to use `find`.  To use `sed` to delete a line, you can either use the non-portable `-i`, or simply write a script to redirect the stream.  For example:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'f=/tmp/t.$$; 
    sed "/<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"/d" $0 > $f; mv $f $0' {} \;
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this command:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '/foobar/d' {} \;
```

Change `foobar` to what you search for.